# How does websites get live Channel coverage

Tags: asp.net, streaming, stream, video-streaming

there are thousand of websites on the internet that have live coverage of the channels ,cricket matches.how does they do that? from where does they pick the coverage? i am asking this because i have no idea . any input will lead me to go further in the implementation

i want to implement this in an asp.net website

Answer (score 1):

Live channels and live matches gives rights to particular websites and also access giving to there gateways after paying huge amount of money and hence they can able to show live telecast.But if you want to try out such application then there are some open source streaming servers which you can use to create your own application in .Net

FluorineFX http://fluorinefx.com/

Red5 http://osflash.org/red5

RubyIZUMI http://code.google.com/p/rubyizumi/

Kaltura http://osflash.org/kaltura

haxeVideo http://code.google.com/p/haxevideo

For .net FluorineFx looks cool.